# Make image double height of sibling (hard to topic)

Tags: css, sass

I’m struggling to make the large image on the right be in line visually with the other items when the screen scales.

Flexbox or grid can be used if they make this possible I just wasn't sure how to achieve this using those tools.

Thanks

```
<section class="content-wrap sleep-smart">

 <div class="col-1-of-3 fold">
 <a href="#">
 <img class="sleep-smart__img sleep-smart__img--beds" src="http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/img/folding-beds.jpg" alt="xxx">
 <div class="sleep-smart__title-box">
 <h3 class="sleep-smart__h3">Folding Beds</h3>
 <span class="sleep-smart__faux-link">Discover<br>More</span>
 </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/qwerty-design/pen/PQVzaL?editors=1100

Comment: Would you like to make the large image on the right to be of the same height as the two images to its left?

Comment: @HossamHussien, I believe that is what the OP would like. I'm also going to assume they don't want it stretch and probably not cropped.

Comment: Yes. Just so it lines up with the smaller images at all breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in many ways one of them is to use CSS grid. You can find a good guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

> To make an HTML element behave as a grid container, you have to set the display property to **grid** or **inline-grid**. Grid containers consist of grid items, placed inside columns and rows.

```css
.grid-container {
  /*Must set display to grid or inline-grid*/
  display: grid;
  
  /*Define number of columns and column width*/
  /*Here we define 3 columns each of which is 33% of its parent width*/
  /*You can set each column with different width e.g.(100px, 200px, 50px)*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  
   /*Define number of rows and row height*/
  /*Here we define 2 rows each of which is 100px*/
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  
  /*Spaces between columns*/
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  
  /*Spaces between rows*/
  grid-row-gap: 10px
}
/*Just for demo*/
.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5 {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff
}
/*For each item, select its position you can think of it as a table and point to each cell with (row,col)*/
.item-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.item-5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hossam. This isn't quite what I want though as the heights can't remain fixed. They need to scale to keep the aspect ratio of the image. I had a version working like this with my float based layout but it doesn't work with the images.